# How long it usually takes for Firebase Firestore to cost money?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got an app, where I load Data from Cloud Firestore, and I load the data every time, someone opens the page.

Now I saw that my reading Process gets really high, and I am only one user.

I hope someone can tell me how long it usually takes for firebase to cost money.

It would also be cool to know, on what I have to focus while working with Cloud Firestore.

The last Question I have, is about the way I load my data, I am very new to coding in general and I have no Clue, about how you normally load data. I just did it this way because it worked.
Is it normal to load the data every time you open the page, or should the data only be loaded the first time you open the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you load data depends on the requirements of app. If you want a more realtime synced app, then loading on every run is important. If the data you are querying doesn't change that often like-profile data, then storing in on local system will reduce the cost a lot.

For pricing see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). You can perform 50K/day document reads which is more than enough during development.

As for coding style, in the initial phase, just code in general. Once the app development is complete, optimize the code. The place where data need not be realtime can be replaced with a one-time read code or a local copy of data. This says a lot of costs.

This answer talks on how to reduce cost while using realtime database. It can also be implemented on Cloud Firestore. [How to reduce firebase realtime database download cost?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727291/11783181)